# Asynchronous loading of data from multiple api

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous

Loading data from one api request and storing it in one array (suppose n object coming in response json object),
and another api request takes argument from first api request and loads status of n objects.

1) first api request will load n objects and display it into table:

```
dispatch_queue_t loadDataQueue = dispatch_queue_create("loadDataQueue",NULL);
dispatch_async(loadDataQueue, ^{      
    // Perform long running process
    [self loadData];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // Update the UI
        [tableView reloadData];
        [self hideActivityView];
    });
});
```

2) now I am calling `loadstatus` method, it takes parameter from `objectatindex` and loads status data for `objectatindex`. So this method calling n times in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

```
dispatch_queue_t loadStatusQueue = dispatch_queue_create("loadStatusQueue",NULL);
dispatch_async(loadStatusQueue, ^{     
    // Perform long running process
    [self loadStatus];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
        // Update the UI
        [tableView reloadData];
    });
});
```

This updates one row at a time. So reloading table n times.
It takes so time to load status of all objects.
Some time hanging problem occured.

Can somebody please provide efficient solution for this or other way to do this?

Comment: @sanjeet Your comment is completely unrelated. What he would like to do is to improve his code to prevent reloading the table too frequently & unnecessarily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The info in your question was a bit unclear ( especially about `objectAtIndex`... Does it mean that in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you get the cell's info, then based on that you send another async request to get it's status?)

It might not be enough to tell all reasons could make your app slow, but I could say it's not a good idea to reload the whole table just to update one cell. Also I think you should call `loadData` to get full data list of basic info first, then call `loadStatus` for 'visible' cells.

I guess you know how to store the loaded data/status in arrays to prevent refetching data. So the example below is possibly what you could adopt to improve the performance:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath   
    UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ReusableCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    [cell configureData:self.loadedData[indexPath.row]];

    if (self.loadedStatus[indexPath.row]) {
        // If the status has been loaded then
        [cell configureStatus:self.loadedStatus[indexPath.row]];
    } else {
        dispatch_queue_t loadStatusQueue = dispatch_queue_create("loadStatusQueue",NULL);

        __weak __typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
        dispatch_async(loadStatusQueue, ^{
            __strong __typeof(weakSelf) strongSelf = weakSelf;
            if (!strongSelf) {
                return;
            }

            // Perform your long running process here
            // Eg: [strongSelf loadStatusForIndex:indexPath.row];

            UITableViewCell *blockCell = (UITableViewCell *)[strongSelf.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [strongSelf.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
            });
        }
                       });
        ....
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: thanks ducky.. its little helpful.. but its not complete solution... in above solution only two threads running. one main thread and one background thread.. can you suggest me some other method for loading data. i want to start n threads for n rows. is it possible ?

Comment: Hm? If you really want to make more thread than that why don't you just name the status fetching thread differently?

Comment: It's also a good idea to learn about NSOperationQueue as well.